# Wireless internet only working sometimes!

Tags: wireless

I've recently installed Ubuntu on my desktop, wich also has windows 7. Everything, but the wireless internet, is working fine.

My wireless internet connection is for some reason only working sometimes. I can always see internet's and connect to them. But when i'm connected to my own net, it only work in the beginning. Then it doesn't, but it's still connected to the wireless net.

When i disconnect and connect to the internet it works again, for at short time, and then it don't. I've disabled ipv6, and that made the internet become faster, when it works.

Is there anything i can do about this?

Answer (score 0):

Post more details. Here's what you can do though:

Try disabling ipv6 (this is the most likely culprit):

```
sudo gedit /etc/sysctl.conf
```

Now add these lines:

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

Save.

Alternatively, goto System Settings > Software & Updates (under the System Tab) > Additional Drivers and enable (or disable) the manufacturer's driver.

Comment: Please open the terminal(ctrl+alt+t) run the commands one line at a time: `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net`
`lsusb`
`nm-tool`
`sudo iwlist scan`
`iwconfig`
`rfkill list all`